# How to merge new csv file as a new column into an existing csv file using php or even javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, csv, merge

I have a few csv file with 1 column and multiple rows of data as follow:

file1.csv:
Monday
Adam
Andrew

file2.csv:
Tuesday
James
Sally
Sean
Ben
Sid

file3.csv:
Wednesday
Conny
Steve
Albert

How can I take the data from these 3 files and place them as separate column in a new csv file?
I am using php and javasript and if any of this can do the job will be good.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - and let us know what you have tried to solve this problem. People here will be happy to help, but are unlikely to do the whole job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to do this on the JS side using the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

It's definitely possible to do it on the PHP side. Here's [related documentation on handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

To read a CSV file, check out [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv). Use this to get the contents of each file into an array.

At that point, you should be able to do something like this:

```php
<?php

// $file1 = ...
// $file2 = ...
// $file3 = ...

$rows = [];
$row_count = max(count($file1), count($file2), count($file3));
for ($row_index = 0; $row_index < $row_count; $row_index++) {
    $row = [];
    $row[0] = $file1[$row_index] ?? '';
    $row[1] = $file2[$row_index] ?? '';
    $row[2] = $file3[$row_index] ?? '';
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Once you've got the data you want to write to the new file into its own array (i.e. `$rows` in the above example), you can use [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/fputcsv) to write it.

Comment: [Null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get it to work base on a part of your codes above. First I need to get the data from each file into a simple array since they only have 1 column each. Then I count the rows in each file and get the max count like what you did. Finally I place the data from each file into the for loop like below:

```
for ($row_index = 0; $row_index < $row_count; $row_index++) {
$row = array($mondaycol[$row_index], $tuesdaycol[$row_index] , $wednesdaycol[$row_index], $thursdaycol[$row_index], $fridaycol[$row_index], $saturdaycol[$row_index], $sundaycol[$row_index]);


fputcsv($outFile, $row);
```

}